# Capturing the color in between?

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with my assignment for java. The assignment is:

Create a game where:
There are two playing pieces, black and white ones.
When a piece or a line of pieces is surrounded by its opponents on both the left and the right sides or both the front and back, it is said to be captured and its color changes to the color of the pieces that surrounded it.
On your turn, you must capture at least one of your opponent’s piece.
The game ends when user has no more valid moves.
And the winner is assigned to the player who captured more pieces.

The board is 6x6 and you only need to display the results in words, not an actual game. I only know how to create a board using arrays. I don't know how to code the actual game. Some help would be much appreciated!! I know I have to use a lot of "if" statements and loops but I don't know how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
boardA[0] = "A1";
boardA[1] = "A2";
boardA[2] = "A3";
boardA[3] = "A4";
boardA[4] = "A5";
boardA[5] = "A6";

boardB[0] = "B1";
boardB[1] = "B2";
boardB[2] = "B3";
boardB[3] = "B4";
boardB[4] = "B5";
boardB[5] = "B6";

boardC[0] = "C1";
boardC[1] = "C2";
boardC[2] = "C3";
boardC[3] = "C4";
boardC[4] = "C5";
boardC[5] = "C6";

boardD[0] = "D1";
boardD[1] = "D2";
boardD[2] = "D3";
boardD[3] = "D4";
boardD[4] = "D5";
boardD[5] = "D6";

boardE[0] = "E1";
boardE[1] = "E2";
boardE[2] = "E3";
boardE[3] = "E4";
boardE[4] = "E5";
boardE[5] = "E6";

boardF[0] = "F1";
boardF[1] = "F2";
boardF[2] = "F3";
boardF[3] = "F4";
boardF[4] = "F5";
boardF[5] = "F6";
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("This is how the board looks like:" + "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardA) + 
                   "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardB)+ "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardC) 
                     +"\n"+ Arrays.toString(boardD) +"\n"+Arrays.toString(boardE)
                  + "\n"+Arrays.toString(boardF));
System.out.println("The board has 6 blocks, starting with 4 people in the middle, 2 black and 2 white facing each other.");
boardC[2] = "white";
boardC[3] = "black";
boardD[2] = "black";
boardD[3] = "white";
System.out.println("The board starts with: " + "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardA) + 
                   "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardB)+ "\n" + Arrays.toString(boardC) 
                     +"\n"+ Arrays.toString(boardD) +"\n"+Arrays.toString(boardE)
                  + "\n"+Arrays.toString(boardF));
System.out.println("You are white. Where do you want to move?");
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's not much and doesn't compile like it's presented here. So what exactly did you try apart from just writing down an array? Where are your specific problems? We will not do your assignment for you, but we can help you if you ask more precise questions than: "How to do this assignment?". Try to think about a loop with a condition for when the game ends and which moves are allowed in each turn and their outcomes. Try to write some code about that and then share it with us, so that we can get a better idea of your problem. I bet you have information on how to solve it from your course.

Comment: I really have no idea. My professor just threw it at us without showing us any directions. The last thing we did was just creating objects and messing around with the do-while loop. And I just want to ask on how do I make the program knows if the pieces are surrounded then the color switch. Do I use the if-else statement to write down every single possible move or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely asking for... a LOT. We can't do your assignment for you!

I believe that you should really just start by **writing some stuff**, little by little.
For example, you could:

1. make it work maybe for one particular case at first,
2. then an other,
3. then see some pattern and make it generic...

---

I'll get you started, though.
I think that your interaction with the user should look like that:

```
boolean gameEnded = false;
boolean isWhitesTurn = true;
while(!gameEnded) {
   System.out.println("You are" + (isWhitesTurn)?"white":"black" + ". Where do you want to move?");
   final String input = keyboard.nextLine();

   // process the input here

   isWhitesTurn = !isWhitesTurn; // every time, you toggle between the players.
}
System.out.println("Game over.");
```

---

Now, in order to process the input, we can first **assume that the user will input a valid `String`**. That is, the coordinates of some actual board case.
**Later, you'll have to check this** and deal with the wrong inputs.

Here is what you have to do with that imput:

1. translate that `String` to some `Object`: *e.g.*: `"E5"` should mean `boardE[4]`. I guess that you could create some methods like `getValueAt(final String coordinates)` and `setValueAt(final String coordinates)`.
2. check if there is already a player at those coordinates (using `getValueAt()`).

   2.1 If there is, ask for a new input.
   2.2 If there isn't, place the player's colour at the right coordinates (using `setValueAt()`), then execute the algorithm that changes the colours of the surrounded "players". You know what I mean.
3. there must be some kind of condition that stops the game (*e.g.*: no more empty case on the board). Check it. If the game is supposed to end, set `gameEnded = true;`

---

Since I'm at it, I would suggest your **board** to look more like an actual board, that is... a **matrix**.

For instance, I would use this:

```
private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 6;
private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;
final String[][] board = new String[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
```

and initialize it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++) {
    final String letter = new Character((char) ('A' + i)).toString();
    for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++) {
        this.board[i][j] = letter + String.valueOf(j);
    }
}
```

then print it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++) {
        System.out.print(this.board[i][j] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

I hope that all this will get you started properly ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. And I didn't mean to ask you guys to do the assignment for me I'm so sorry I didn't even realize that!! I just wanted to ask how can I code it so that the program knows if two pieces are surrounded then the surrounded pieces have to switch colors? I thought about writing down every possible move like if you go E3 then D2 becomes white, else if you go C3 then C2 becomes white and so on. But that would take too long wouldn't it? Is there like a faster way to do that?

Comment: It's ok, I know you didn't ask us to do you assignment :) To check that, you have to iterate through each line and column of your board and check if there is a sequence like `black, white, white, white, ... black` anywhere. If so, replace all these `white`s by some `black`s. Seriously, try doing what I suggested and I'm pretty sure you should be able to make it kinda work :) I will gladly help you more if you show us some more code ;)